# Cannot run tor relay on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: configuration, relays, linux, tor-install

I have a server with Ubuntu Linux 16.04.
I installed tor like written in https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu (chose Xenial repos).
I wrote what I believe to be the correct rows in the Tor config file, but I executed:

```
sudo service tor restart
```

(also tried start argument).
As well as

```
/etc/init.d/tor start
```

But in the end I received this error:

```
/usr/bin/pkttyagent: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-login.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no libsystemd-login.so.0 file in system. Packages.ubuntu.com says there is no package that provides that file in Xenial, only in Trusty.

How can I run a tor relay on my Xenial-based system?

Comment: You want to use the `service` command, not /etc/init.d/tor. What does `sudo journalctl -u tor@default --no-pager` output?

Comment: @canonizingironize his problem was the Tor binary package built for a previous version of Ubuntu: the library tor complains about is a systemd-integration part and it's package was removed in later Ubuntu releases. It's sad, but the repository maintainers do not use either a proper reposiroty setup, or a static build. That's where such a "glitches" are popping out from. The Ubuntu problem is really annoying - with the packages just removed at will, so the "backporting" trick I've mentioned in my answer is quite a common medicine for this kind of problems

Comment: So it's an issue with package dependencies in their ubuntu setup and your proposed solution did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the apt sources from Xenial and try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libsystemd-login0 libsystemd-login-dev
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: No packages libsystemd-login0 and libsystemd-login-dev.

Comment: у тебя старый пакет тора - из репозитария. поэтому - если УЖ ОЧЕНЬ ХОЧЕТСЯ использовать именно его, то добавь старые пакеты и поставь их. IMHO - just IMHO - tor правильнее собирать из исходников